# uploadable Namespace handling

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

The following links and text snippets describe and reference the "uploadable" parameter for field in SMW Forms (hope this is the right issue tracker for this)

Specifies that a link should be placed next to this field, that opens a popup window to let the user upload a file; see "Uploading files", below. See

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Defining_forms#.27field.27_tag
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Defining_forms#Uploading_files

The type of the target property seems to have to be Page for this to work, there is no special standard datatype for images in:

https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:List_of_datatypes

There are explanations in how this works at:

http://smw.referata.com/wiki/Using_Semantic_Forms_for_file_pages_and_uploads
http://discoursedb.org/wiki/Form:Images_test
http://discoursedb.org/wiki/Special:FormEdit/Images_test/ImageTest

and there has been a discussion how to handle the "File:" namespace prefix:
http://semediawiki-devel.narkive.com/gm7hJMBE/smw-devel-sf-turning-uploadable-into-input-type-upload

Now I assume that at this point the "File:" part is not handled by the uploadable flag (at least not by default).

It would be great to have solution (or if one exists a proper documentation pointer to it) that allows the File: prefix to be added automatically so that the full page description File:someImage is available as the result of "uploadable".

**What would be a workaround or solution or pointer to a solution for this?**

I have filed a bug report at 
* https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/issues/1036 
to notify the developers

Answer (score 1):

I always use a property of datatype text for storing the file names and I never add the namespace to this property. Thus I can do whatever I like with the stored value in the template which is holding it, i.e. link it to "Media:" or to "File:".

You could e.g. do [[Is file::File:{{{File|}}}]] in the template to add the namespace if you would really like to add the namespace directly.